# I wonder about a secure gateway of IBM using a web socket?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I want to consider using a Bluemix to run my application? For a firewall problem, I want to use a secure gateway of IBM that is one service in Bluemix. It uses a web socket. I customized a web socket of jetty in the past. So I am wondering if a web socket client makes a permanent connection with a web socket server. Does the server giving data back to the client? If the connection is disconnected for some reason, how can the web socket handle this exception?

Comment: You should probably use a library to handle this for you, rather than manually checking for a heartbeat. What library are you using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  you mean, I have to make my own retry logic in my application that would be a server of gateway? or you mean there are some other libraries for failover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering about how Bluemix Secure Gateway handles these situations, then yes, the Secure Gateway Client creates a persistent secure websocket connection to the Secure Gateway Servers which allows for the necessary communication between your application and your resource(s) behind the firewall.  If the websocket connection goes down, the Secure Gateway Client will attempt to establish a new websocket connection with the Secure Gateway Servers.